# Jenkins - During a Maven release how can the user select the profile to use?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I have two profiles in my Maven project (`foo` and `bar`) and I need the user to select a profile when they perform a release in Jenkins.

How can I force the user to select a Maven profile during the release?

To be clear, I am only talking about the **Perform Maven Release**. I do not need the parameter when building.

Ideally this would be on the same page where the user has to enter the versions for the release.

I have tried ticking **Configure release build** (in the section titled Build Environment), and adding a **Choice Parameter**, but I am never prompted when I click on Perform Maven Release.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use a parametrized build and add a Parameter Profile, which can have the values foo and bar. then you add -P{foo} to the release command line

Comment: @Jens Your suggestion works (with `-P$myChoiceName`), but ideally it would just be the release that was parameterise, not the build. (Many thanks for your comment, maybe write an answer?)

Comment: i have added my comment as an answer. sorry do not understand `but ideally it would just be the release that was parameterise, not the build`

Answer (score 3):

Use a parametrized build and add a Parameter `activeProfile`, which can have the values foo and bar. Then you add `-P${activeProfile}` to the release command line

Comment: -P${activeProfile} :)

Comment: @MadJlzz Thanks habe changed it.

Comment: It's ${activeProfile} not {$activeProfile}. I didn't see any change.